# Consume python package from Azure feed in a local (not Azure) docker instance

Tags: python, azure, docker, package, python-keyring

I have created a PoC Azure pipeline to create a package in a feed, as below:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.7'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'
  displayName: 'Deploy Python 3.7'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install twine
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'


- script: |
    python setup.py sdist
  displayName: 'Package creation'


- task: TwineAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: 'Project/Feed'
  displayName: 'Set Artifact Authentiation'


- script: 'twine upload -r Feed --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*'
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
```

I am trying to do a pip install in a docker instance on my laptop (not Azure) using the following:

```
FROM python:3.7.9-buster

ADD . /package-consumer/

RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0

RUN pip install keyring artifacts-keyring

RUN  pip install --index-url=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Org/Project/_packaging/Feed/pypi/simple/ Package

CMD cd /package-consumer && python Consume/UsePackages.py
```

And as expected I get

```
[Minimal] [CredentialProvider]DeviceFlow: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/causewayltd/Mobile/_packaging/Mobile/pypi/simple/
[Minimal] [CredentialProvider]ATTENTION: User interaction required. 

    **********************************************************************

    To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code **** to authenticate.

    **********************************************************************

[Error] [CredentialProvider]Device flow authentication failed. User was presented with device flow, but didn't react within 90 seconds.
```

I tried various settings such as `ENV ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE true` etc. All to no avail.

Is it even possible to pip install an Azure package in a non Azure docker container. If so, how? Any help appreciated.

PS - I have scoured the web but can't seem to get a definitive answer how to achieve the above. Thanks

Comment: I answered a similar question here where the solution was to mount a volume to the location that `SessionTokenCache.dat` is written in.  In this case we are using devcontainer.json, so your solution may be a bit different without it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519861/sharing-artifacts-keyring-authentication-and-pip-conf-with-devcontainer-to-reach/73159505#73159505

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution (prob a bit hacky).. generate a token in Azure
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page and copy the token.

And in the Dockerfile ensure `pip install keyring artifacts-keyring` is not there.

Then simply

```
RUN  pip install --index-url=https://<azure_pat>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/Org/Project/_packaging/Feed/pypi/simple/ Package
```

Where <azure_pat> is the copied token.

Answer (score 1):

If you've used [artifacts-keyring](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-keyring) to install packages from your feed on your local machine, you can share the cached credentials which are [stored locally](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#session-token-cache-locations) using this in your dockerfile:

```
# install the artifacts-keyring which will be used to authenticate to the private feed
RUN pip install twine keyring artifacts-keyring
# create the directory where the session token cache will be stored
RUN mkdir -p /root/.local/share/MicrosoftCredentialProvider
# temporarily mount the session token cache from the build context to the container and use it to install the package
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=SessionTokenCache_dat,dst=/root/.local/share/MicrosoftCredentialProvider/SessionTokenCache.dat \
  pip install MyPrivatePackage --index-url=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<MyOrg>/_packaging/<MyRepo>/pypi/simple/  \
```

Then build your image providing the cached credentials as a secret:

```bash
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=SessionTokenCache_dat,src=$HOME/.local/share/MicrosoftCredentialProvider/SessionTokenCache.dat .
```

Windows users will need to change the [location of the token cache](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#session-token-cache-locations) appropriately.

This answer is adapted from the official docs for [safely installing nuget packages using the artifact credential provider](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#using-the-azure-artifact-credential-provider)